# How to change the size of columns in DataGrid of react-mui depending on the screen size

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, components, sizing

I want the title column takes 3/4 of the full row width and the amount column tackes 1/4 of the full row width in all screens (md, sx...).
This is the code:

```
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
return (
<Box   sx={{height: { md: 450, xs: 350 }, width: '35%',}} >
  <DataGrid
    columns={[
      { field: 'title',},
      { field: 'amount'
      }
    ]}
    rows={[
      { id: 1, title: 'React', amount:'100' },
      { id: 2, title: 'MUI', amount:'-100' },
    ]}
  />
</Box>
)
}
export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-dimensions/

```
columns={[
      { field: 'title', flex: 3},
      { field: 'amount', flex: 1}
    ]}
```